# Replace IBM MQ Message Payload and reply with same message in Java (Without JMS)

Tags: java, ibm-mq

We have a requirement to reply to a response queue with the same message from request queue after processing the payload. I am facing issue while trying to write string to incoming message. The processing message is getting appended to existing payload. Here is the code snippet I am using

```
public void readFromQueue(String reqQueue, String queueMgrName) {
        int depth = 0;
        MQQueueManager queueMgr = null;
        MQQueue queue = null;
        MQHeaderList headerList = null;
        try {
            queueMgr = getQueueManager(); //queue manager is initiated
            queue = getQueue("get", queueMgr); // queue is intiated
            MQGetMessageOptions getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions(); // Message GET options
            getOptions.options = MQConstants.MQGMO_WAIT + MQConstants.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + 
                                 MQConstants.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG + 
                                 MQConstants.MQGMO_PROPERTIES_FORCE_MQRFH2;
            byte[] b = null;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    message = new MQMessage();
                    queue.get(message, getOptions);
                    headerList = new MQHeaderList(message, true);
                    processMessage(headerList, message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } 
             }
}

public void processMessage(MQHeaderList headerList, MQMessage message) {
      String receivedRequest = headerList.getBody().toString();
      /* ---- Message processing logic here ---- */
      message.writeString(outMessage);
      writeToQueue(message);
}   
public void writeToQueue (MQMessage putMsg)
            throws MQDataException, ConfigurationException { 
        MQQueueManager queueMgr = null;
        MQQueue queue = null;
        try {
            queueMgr = getQueueManager();
            queue = getQueue("put", queueMgr);
            MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            queue.put(putMsg, pmo);
            queueMgr.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception mqex) {
            System.out.println(mqex);
        } 
}
```

Example payload message:

```
{
   Msg:{
        MsgHeader: {
            headerKey1: headerValue1,
            headerKey2: headerValue2
        },
        MsgBody: {
            bodyKey1: bodyValue1,
            bodyKey2: bodyValue2
        }
}
```

Expected payload in response message:

```
{
   Msg:{
        MsgHeader: {
            headerKey1: headerValue1,
            headerKey2: headerValue2
        },
        MsgBody: {
            newBodyKey1: newBodyValue1,
            newBodyKey2: newBodyValue2,
        }
}
```

Acutal payload in the response message: (Appended to actual payload instead of replacing it)

```
{
   Msg:{
        MsgHeader: {
            headerKey1: headerValue1,
            headerKey2: headerValue2
        },
        MsgBody: {
            bodyKey1: bodyValue1,
            bodyKey2: bodyValue2
        }
}
{
   Msg:{
        MsgHeader: {
            headerKey1: headerValue1,
            headerKey2: headerValue2
        },
        MsgBody: {
            newBodyKey1: newBodyValue1,
            newBodyKey2: newBodyValue2,
        }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: It appears to be a problem in your application message processing logic. MQ will put whatever message payload your application is providing. Check your message processing logic.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Processed message can be a small JSON string also. The issue is it is being appended to original payload every time in the reply message.

Comment: Just get rid of this `message.writeString(outMessage);`.  `message` already contains the body,  why append it again?

Comment: Or call `message.clearMessage()` to clear the incoming message buffer before calling `writeString`.

Comment: I'll post an answer if this is what you ate looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am processing the message and again trying to write back to original message without disturbing any headers in the message. If we use clearMessage() the MQRFH2 headers will also be cleared, causing error com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2142' (MQRC_HEADER_ERROR)

Comment: Why not set `MQGMO_PROPERTIES_IN_HANDLE`?

Comment: This excellent post from Roger Matt help if you want to delve into the rfh2 header.  https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=4811

Comment: And this post on how to construct a rfh2 header.  https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=4823

Comment: I will try to implement the above solution and let you know. Thanks

Comment: The above solution is not working for me as I need to grab the payload, process it and send back with the same request message or with same request message headers

Comment: MQConstants.MQGMO_WAIT + MQConstants.MQGMO_PROPERTIES_COMPATIBILITY + MQConstants.MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE + MQConstants.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG + MQConstants.MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE; This combination of get options did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are using the MQHeaderList class.  How many MQ internal headers are in your original request message?

Also, are you trying to put MQMessage objects in a JSON object because your description is very confusing.

It sounds like your request message layout is:

```
{RFH2 header}{mcd folder}{jms folder}{usr folder}{message payload}
```

And you want the reply message to be:

```
{RFH2 header}{mcd folder}{jms folder}{usr folder}{updated message payload}
```

where the RFH2 header, mcd folder, jms folder and usr folder contain the original values of the request message.

If this is what your are trying to do then have a look at another blog [posting](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=5800) and see if it matches what you are trying to do.

---

Updated: Feb. 3, 2020.

To get the message payload from the request message, simply do the following:

```
String msgStr = null;
if (CMQC.MQFMT_STRING.equals(rfh2.getFormat()))
{
   msgStr = requestMsg.readStringOfByteLength(requestMsg.getDataLength());
}
else
{
   byte[] b = new byte[requestMsg.getDataLength()];
   requestMsg.readFully(b);
   msgStr = new String(b);
}
```

Comment: Really thanks for your inputs and effort to help me out. I have to grab the {message payload} and replace it with {updated message payload} as you mentioned. When I am trying to get MQRFH2 headers for setting them to response message, the message payload read throwing exception. That is why I have used MQHeaderList to grab the body using getBody() method and processing the same. In this process it appending as {message payload}{updated message payload}. But in your example you are writing a static text with existing headers to response message. Please help me out.

Comment: If you want the message payload of the request message then see my updated answer above.  Pay attention to the if statement.  It is checking the format field from the RFH2 structure and not the format field of the message's MQMD.

Comment: Ok.  I have updated my original MQTest77.java in the blog posting to generate Powerball numbers based on the checksum of the incoming request message's payload.  Therefore, there is nothing static about the reply message.  See my comments here: https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=5810